# Want to retrieve indexed ethereumwallet js files, the site was shut down. How to retrieve the password book.(ethereum)

Tags: ethereum, blockchain

only October and September files, then how to find July? In 2017,
THE WEB  :https://web.archive.org/web/20170914013740/https://ethereumwallet.com/beta/index.html
But the official website has been shut down
how can i back it？

I only have the url and password, and the js file for October and September, and now the file for July (thirdparty.min.js) is missing, because the official password book was changed at that time, so I can't find it back, before I can open it

At that time, the function of the web address was without private keys and mnemonics，Ethereum was locked for seven years
i need js